# Mysql trigger with two tables and if statement

Tags: mysql, join, if-statement, triggers

I cannot find any solution for this 'problem'.
My database needs to update a field in one table when another table is updated.
(only when the new value is 5 or 7 and the new prop.key is "status_id")
But the updated table doesn't include the values that I need. It only contains an ID to another table.

I am not sure about the syntax for this statement. This one won't work. Can anybode help me?

This is what I tried:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER autoClosedOn AFTER INSERT ON journal_details
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF
        NEW.prop_key = "status_id"
    AND  NEW.value = "5"
    OR  NEW.value = "7"
   THEN
   UPDATE
        issues i
        JOIN journals j
          ON j.journalized_id = i.id
     SET 
        i.closed_on = j.created_on;
     WHERE  j.id = NEW.jounal_id;
   END IF;
  END$$

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a superfluous semicolon before the `WHERE` clause of your update statement.